# How can I add more variables to this ajax post...?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making a game and I need to send some variables via a post request to a leaderboards page.

This is my current post code:

```
var toDatabase = confirm('Do you want to save your score to the database?');
if (toDatabase) {
    $.post("leaderboards.php", {"Level1": "Level1"}, function() {
    window.location.href="leaderboards.php";
});
} else {
    $.post("gameL2.php", {"Level1": "Level1"}, function() {
      window.location.href='gameL2.php';
    });
}
```

This top code linking to the `leaderboards.php` file is the one I wish to add more variables too. How can this be done? Do I add a new pair of curly braces?

Comment: The examples here might be helpful: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd parameter is simply an object:

```
$.post("leaderboards.php", {"Level1": "Level1", "abc": "def", "num": 123}, function() {
```

Just separate with commas

Answer (score 4):

Data is sent via an object, just add another key/val:

```
$.post("leaderboards.php", {"Level1": "Level1", "anotherKey": "anotherVal"}, function() {
```

Comment: `"anotherKey": "anotherVal"` :)

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for :) (will accept when it allows me to).

Answer (score 1):

You will just add more variables to your data object.

```
if (toDatabase) {
    $.post("leaderboards.php", {"Level1": "Level1","variable1":0,"variable2":"value","variable3":546}, function() {
    window.location.href="leaderboards.php";
});
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a base object you wish to send, and it only gets added two in the two different events happening to then you can use `jQuery.extend`

```
var baseObj = {
   Level1: "Level1"
}

if (toDatabase) {
    $.extend(baseObj, { complete: true });
}else{
    $.extend(baseObj, {doSomething: "yeah" });
}
```

This takes the idea of just adding another key/val pair a bit further and more flexible